# JSON_API don't return data on wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, json-api, wordpress-json-api

I had a problem about `wordpress`.

I used `wordpress 4.5.3` with plugin `json-api 1.1.1` and i installed `wordpress` on `ubuntu 16.04`, i used `apache2` and `php7`.

When i installed and activated plugin `json-api` on `wordpress`. When i clicked link `get_recent_posts` it returned

```
The requested URL /api/get_recent_posts/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 172.16.1.38 Port 80
```

This is file config virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  #ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't know what is problem ? Hope everybody can explained for me, why it don't work ?

Comment: Try to use `/?json=get_recent_posts` just to make sure that the plugin is working !

Comment: This link `/api/get_recent_posts/` is a link after you configured .htaccess.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH: I tried `http://172.16.1.38/?json=get_recent_posts` and it worked. But why i clicked link as default and it didn't work.

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn Yup, `.htaccess` was set as default  of `wordpress`

Comment: Try to visit the `permalink` menu in the admin section and try to click save button, The purpose is to refresh rules !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I tried it. But when i clicked  `get_recent_posts` again, it still return `/api/get_recent_posts/ was not found on this server`